# How to use @XStream to display xml for RSS feeds?

Tags: java, xml, xstream, feed

I  am trying to add the below code in java using Xstream annotations. I completely don't understand how should I do it. Currently, I have a class named Channel.java

```
@XStreamAlias("channel")
public class Channel {

    private String link;

    @XStreamAlias("atom:link")
    private AtomLink atom_link;

    private String title;
           
    private String description;

    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<Item> itemList;

    // etc
}
```

Image.java

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

@XStreamAlias("image")
public class Image {
         
    private String URL;

    public String getUrl() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = URL;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the below code in the Channel class. So basically I'm trying to add a subelement  in  for RSS feeds.

```
<image>
    <url>
        Url here
    </url> 
</image>
```

Expected XML

```
<channel>
    <title>
    </title>
                 
    <image>
        <url>
        </url>
    </image>

    <item>
    </item>
</channel>
```

How do I do this? I have Image.java. But how do I get it in Channel.java?

Comment: Question is not clear...Image.java ??

Comment: The image that I have is in Image.java which has other attributes url etc. this is in RSS 2.0

Comment: check this http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html

Comment: I referred that but the above is a little confusing. I have Image.java where I have a variable url. and I want to put that image & url in Channel.java.

Comment: could you post dat Image.java and expected sample xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

@XStreamAlias("channel")
public class Channel {

    private String link;

    @XStreamAlias("atom:link")
    private String atom_link;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    private Image image;

     public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getAtom_link() {
        return atom_link;
    }

    public void setAtom_link(String atom_link) {
        this.atom_link = atom_link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<String> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @XStreamImplicit 
     private List<String> itemList;

}
```

Image.java

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

@XStreamAlias("image")
public class Image {
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Tester.java

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;


public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Channel channel=new Channel();
        Image image=new Image();
        image.setUrl("http:://google.com");
        channel.setAtom_link("atomlink");
        channel.setImage(image);
        channel.setDescription("desc");
         XStream xstream = new XStream();
         xstream.alias("channel", Channel.class);

         System.out.println(xstream.toXML(channel));


    }

}
```

output:-

```
<channel>
  <atom__link>atomlink</atom__link>
  <description>desc</description>
  <image>
    <url>http:://google.com</url>
  </image>
</channel>
```

check this... this may not be the exact answer but u can get something from here..If i get your Expected XML file exactely ..i can provide u better solution